# SmbException failed to connect hostname/IP_address throwing with proper credentials in Java

Tags: java, maven, authentication, smb, jcifs

I need to connect to a shared folder with proper user credentials (username, password, domain).
Then when I have access to the folder, I need to list the subfolders and files in it.

Im trying with the  `jcifs.smb.SmbFile` class and `jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication` for the authentication.

My code is the following:

```
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domainName", "userName", "password");
SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile("smb://servername/someFolder", auth);
for (String fileName : smbFile.list()) {
   System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

I would be able to connect to the server with these credentials, but I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: servername/IP_ADDR
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:981)
...
```

Anyone has any idea why am I unable to connect?

SmbFile - https://www.jcifs.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/smb/SmbFile.html

NtlmPasswordAuthentication - https://javadoc.io/static/eu.agno3.jcifs/jcifs-ng/2.1.3/jcifs/smb/NtlmPasswordAuthentication.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution!

Because of my OS (Windows 10) I needed to use SMB2 not SMB1 (this is the default).

Solution:

1. Open powershell as an administrator
2. You need to set a property: `Set -SmbServerConfiguration -EnableSMB2Protocol $true`
   Optional: I think it isn't necessarry but I turned off the SMB1 protocol wit the

`Set -SmbServerConfiguration -EnableSMB1Protocol $false` command.

Then you can check the properties with: `Get -SmbServerConfiguration` command, and be sure about that all of the properties have the right value.

3. Import the proper dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.agno3.jcifs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcifs-ng</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

https://github.com/AgNO3/jcifs-ng

4. Finally the code:

```
public static void sendRequest() throws Exception {
        CIFSContext base = SingletonContext.getInstance();
        CIFSContext authed1 = base.withCredentials(new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(base, "domainName",
                "userName", "password"));
        try (SmbFile f = new SmbFile("smb:\\serverName\folder", authed1)) {
            if (f.exists()) {
                for (SmbFile file : f.listFiles()) {
                    System.out.println(file.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am getting Network Name Cannot be found issue sometimes , how can we make this more stable

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change anything using powershell commands. Is there any way to set this in the spring boot application?

Comment: @lukaszFD Are you using your application in a windows environment?